# In a Banach space, the closed convex hull of a compact set is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, compactness, banach-spaces

I'm trying to prove this result. Could you verify if my attempt is fine?

> In a Banach space, the closed convex hull of a compact set is compact.

I post my proof separately as below answer. If other people post an answer, of course I will happily accept theirs. Otherwise, this allows me to subsequently remove this question from unanswered list.

Comment: Please stop doing this. Why would one prefer your proof to the one  in any book on FA?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I just come across this result and would like to give it a try. I guess this is more beneficial (to me) than directly looking up the proof on some books. Sometimes, there are subtle errors that I could not recognize. That's why I post my proof and ask for a verification/comments/suggestions.

Comment: If you are asking for a verification of your proof that that proof should be part of the *question.*

Comment: For proof verification you are supposed to post the answer inside the question. If you think you are making  a significant contribution and others would be benefitted you can post your own answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Of course, including the proof into the *question* is no problem to me. Usually, people only post comments under the question. This makes my question rest in the unanswered list even though I do get an answer (in a form of a comment). This kind of separation allows me to subsequently remove this question from unanswered list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $X$ is a Banach space and $K$ its compact subset. We want to prove that $\overline{\operatorname{conv} K}$ is compact. It [suffices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109550/totally-bounded-complete-implies-compact) to show that $\overline{\operatorname{conv} K}$ is totally bounded.

> **Lemma 1:** Let $(E, d)$ be a metric space. If $K \subset E$ is totally bounded, then so is its closure $\overline K$.
>
> *Proof:* Fix $r>0$. There is $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in K$ such that $\{B(x_i, r/2)\}_{i=1}^n$ covers $K$. Clearly,
> $$
> \overline K \subset \overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^n B(x_i, r/2)} \subset \overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^n \overline B(x_i, r/2)}= \bigcup_{i=1}^n \overline B(x_i, r/2) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n B(x_i, r).
> $$
> The claim then follows.

By our **Lemma 1**, it suffices to show $\operatorname{conv} K$ is totally bounded. By **Lemma 2** below, it suffices to prove that $K$ is totally bounded. This is trivially true because $K$ is compact.

> [Lemma 2:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464651/if-k-subset-e-is-totally-bounded-then-so-is-its-convex-hull-operatornamec/4464655#4464655) Let $(E, d)$ be a metric space. If $K \subset E$ is totally bounded, then so is its convex hull $\operatorname{conv} K$.

Comment: Thank you @daw! edited :v